# Subsetting in R by containing instead of equaling

Tags: r

Currently trying to make a subset of a dataframe of IMDb ratings in R filtered by genre. Using the following command `averageRatingHorror = subset(df_ratings, df_ratings$genres == "Horror")`

I understand that this makes a subset of the dataframe showing only results that have the genre identical to "Horror", but some movies contain more than one genre. e.g "Horror,Fantasy". I have seen some things similar in SQL where you use a % to mean anything after that but sometimes Horror is not the first thing in the list.

So my question is, how do I adapt the command to subset by containing "Horror" instead of equaling "Horror"

EDIT: Answer is as follows, `averageRatingHorror = subset(df_ratings, grepl("Horror", genres))`, thanks to those who offered help.

Comment: look into `%in%` if you what you are looking for is in a vector, or some sort of string matching like `grep` it is string

Comment: Analogous to SQL's `%` is regular expressions, such as `subset(df, grepl("Horror", genres))`. (BTW: you don't need `df_ratings$` inside the `subset`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use package package stringi.

```
library(stringi)
stri_detect_fixed(df_ratings$genres,"Horror")
```